# Search column for string, return value from that row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a workbook with two tabs:

1. REPORT_TAB and
2. RAWDATA_TAB

My RAWDATA_TAB has standard database looking data:

```
   A          |      B      |      C      |    D
ACCOUNT_KEY   |    AMOUNT   |     DATE    |   FEES
 MGX4421           100         6/15/2018       26
 MGLR200           75          6/15/2018        5
 CXDSTR            150         6/15/2018       50
 18000             45          6/15/2018       10
```

On my REPORT_TAB, I want to search column A above for specific accounts, and return the value in column B.

For example:
For one cell I want to search for "CXDSTR" and return 150
For another cell, I want to specifically search for acct "MGX4421" and return 100

I thought I could accomplish that with something like:

```
=VLOOKUP("MGX4421", RAWDATA_TAB!A1:D10,2,0)
```

which would return 100, but it says #N/A with the green triangle in the cell.

Would this be possible with VLOOKUP, or easier with VBA? or MATCH/INDEX

Comment: What is the value returning with your formula? It seems to be working for me.

Comment: If there's any white space in the same cell as "MGLR200" (i.e. "MGLR200  " or "  MGLR200"), the match will fail; unless you use the value **with** spaces in the VLOOKUP equation.

Comment: To your second question, just do a sum of two VLOOKUP expressions. Column 2 as you've currently implemented for the "amount" + another similar expression specifying `4` as the column index, which will return the "fee".

Comment: thank you for the responses, it is returning #N/A.  I don't see any spaces in the ACCOUNT_KEY, I'm not sure why.  Do I need to specificy that the account I'm looking for "MGLR200" is on the RAWDATA_TAB! as well ?

Comment: It seems like as soon as I put the ACCOUNT_KEY "string" I'm looking for in the VLOOKUP, it gives me an error.  If I swap it with a specific cell it returns the value... the problem is, I don't know if the order of the data is going to change so I can't specifiy an exact cell, I need to search on the unqiue ACCOUNT_KEY and use the data in whatever row that is

Comment: @Jay I'm having trouble replicating your problem, the formula and the data you've given works correctly. Can you please click on the cell that contains your problem formula and in the menus go to Formulas>Formula Auditing>Evaluate formula, and let us know what you find?

Comment: Thanks so much for following up, not sure why it wasn't working for me, but I found a different teachnique that seems to work perfectly for what I'm doing.  I will post it as the answer for anyone else looking to do this @girlvsdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this.  I couldn't get the VLOOKUP to do exactly what I was trying to do, so I used the INDEX-MATCH combo.  Syntax looks like:

=INDEX(RAWDATA_TAB!A1:T1000,MATCH("MGX4421",RAWDATA_TAB!C:C,0),2)

This basically goes to the RAWDATA_TAB, searches for the row which contains the unique account number "MGX4421" and returns the column "2" which in the above example is the [AMOUNT].

I hope this helps anyone